# android test new version of apk with in app purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

How can I test a new apk-version with in app purchases?

I have the current version published at Google Play, and a new version published as "alpha".
The "alpha"-version is signed an uploaded with a new version number.
I have waited 24 hours since I uploaded the new apk-file and the user is added as "test account" (same user as tested the first version), but still I get the "This version of the application is not configured for billing through google play"-error.